# Character of unitary, $1$-dimensional representation

Tags: representation-theory

Take a $1$-dimensional unitary representation. I want to show that the modulus of the character must be equal to $1$, but I do not know how to proceed.

Comment: It would be helpful to see what you have tried so far.  Trying writing down what the definition of the character of a representation is, and what that means in the case when the representation is $1$-dimensional.

Comment: So the character is the trace of the representation. Since in this case the representation is one-dimensional, it is just a number. Therefore, the character must be this number. I'm guessing then that from here one uses unitarity of the representation in some way, but I don't see how ...

Comment: You're absolutely on the right track.  In a unitary representation each matrix you get is a unitary matrix.  So what does a $1 \times 1$ unitary matrix look like?

Comment: Oh, right. I see it now! The Hermitian conjugate of a number is just the complex conjugation of this number. Since this conjugate composed with the original number must equal the identity, I find that the square of the modulus must be equal to 1, whence the claim follows. Is this the correct argument?

Comment: Looks good to me!

Answer (score 0):

From @JoeWolf

A 1-dimensional representation $\chi$ of a group $G$ simply means a homomorphism $\chi:G\rightarrow \mathbb{C}$. So for anything in the group $g\in G$, its representation $\chi(g)$ is just a garden variety complex number. The fact that the representation is unitary means $\chi(g)^*\chi(g)=I$. But in our case $I$ is $1$ and the $*$ operator just means complex conjugation. So we have
$$\chi(g)\overline{\chi(g)}=|\chi(g)|^2=1$$
Note that this only demonstrates $|\chi(g)|=\pm1$. But since the modulus operator returns only non-negative values (in more mathy language we say $|\cdot|:\mathbb{C}\rightarrow\mathbb{R}_\ge0)$ we can conclude $|\chi(g)|=1$.